# AVR C random behaviour when setting flags with enum

Tags: c, enums, avr

I have a Problem with enums and flags which I'm using for a programme state from a AVR C Application on a atmega1280 µC, below is the code how I handle the Flags:

```
typedef enum
{
    ALARM_FLAG,
    ARMED_FLAG,
    RC_AUTH_FLAG,
    ADC_DATA_READY_FLAG,
    PLAY_MUSIC_FLAG,
    PLAY_ALARM_FLAG,
    MUSIC_DREQUEST_FLAG,
    SENSOR_CHANGE_FLAG,
    RFID_DECODED_FLAG,
    RFID_AUTH_FLAG,
    RFID_ENABLE_FLAG,
    RFID_DISABLE_FLAG,
    REMOTE_RX_COMPLETE,
    REMOTE_TX_COMPLETE,
    REDRAW_VOLUME,
    FOOTER_UPDATE_FLAG,
    ADD_RFID_FLAG,
    ERROR_FLAG,
} flag_t;

static volatile uint32_t flags = 0;

uint8_t getFlag(flag_t flag)
{
    return ( (flags & (1<<flag) ) !=0);
}

void setFlag(flag_t flag)
{
    flags |= 1<<flag;
}

void clearFlag(flag_t flag)
{
    flags &= ~(1<<flag);
}
```

Now when i use flags below ADD_RFID_FLAG and ERROR_FLAG everything works fine, but when i use ADD_RFID_FLAG or ERROR_FLAG the flags won't get set.

As the ADD_RFID_FLAG has the value of 16 i suspect that something goes wrong with shifting/bit operations on values greater than 16Bit.
Al tough it's an 8-Bit controller this code should work fine, 16 bit code does and uint32_t is officially supported as far as I know.

Comment: You probably shouldn't assume the first value of your `enum` is `0`.  Explicitly set it: `ALARM_FLAG = 0,`

Comment: @FiddlingBits: ["1443 If the first enumerator has no =, the value of its enumeration constant is 0."](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.7.2.2.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`int` is 16 bits on AVR.](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Type_Layout)

```
uint8_t getFlag(flag_t flag)
{
    return ( (flags & (1L<<flag) ) !=0);
}
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, i definitely should had come up with that myself. I Thought something was wrong with how i handle the shifting for bigger values, thanks you saved me some debugging.